# prompt from user two values at once but saving them in different variables

Tags: r

it is possible to ask for two values and save them in different variables??
For example, I want to ask for the focus of a parabola like this

```
focus = readline(prompt="Enter focus: ")
```

then the user writes (5,6)
I want to save `a=5` and `b=6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass comma-separated string in `readline` input then split it on comma and convert to numeric as separate variables.

```
focus <- readline(prompt="Enter focus: ")
#Enter focus: 5,6
focus <- as.numeric(strsplit(focus, ',')[[1]])
a <- focus[1]
b <- focus[2]
a
#[1] 5
b
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

We could read the entry with `scan` and create two objects in global environment with `list2env`

```
focus <- readline(prompt="Enter focus: ")
#Enter focus: 5,6
list2env(as.list(setNames(scan(text = focus, sep=",",
       what = numeric()), c("a", "b"))), .GlobalEnv)
a
#[1] 5
b
#[1] 6
```